# Replace n last rows with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a data frame `df1`:

```
df1 =

index     col1     col2
1         1        2
2         2        3
3         3        4
4         4        5
5         5        6
6         6        7
```

What I would like to do is for example to replace the last two rows in `col2` with NaN, so the resulting data frame would be:

```
index     col1     col2
1         1        2
2         2        3
3         3        4
4         4        5
5         5        NaN
6         6        NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use indexing by positions with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), so need position by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for column:

```
df.iloc[-2:, df.columns.get_loc('col2')] = np.nan
```

Or use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with indexing `df.index`:

```
df.loc[df.index[-2:], 'col2'] = np.nan
```

---

```
print (df)
   col1  col2
1     1   2.0
2     2   3.0
3     3   4.0
4     4   5.0
5     5   NaN
6     6   NaN
```

Last if need integer column:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('Int64')
print (df)
   col1  col2
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     3     4
4     4     5
5     5  <NA>
6     6  <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try:

```
df.col2[-2:] = np.NaN
```

Comment: I think your solution is not recommneded, check [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), `In [353]`. Here need `DataFrame.loc` or `DataFrame.iloc`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael Is there any particular reason why pandas are still allowing it? When is it recommended to use a notation like mine?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the post is going to gather all the possible ways

```
df["col2"].iloc[-2:,] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

4 ways to do this. Ways 3 and 4 seem the best to me:

1)

```
df.at[5,'col2']=math.nan
df.at[6,'col2']=math.nan
```

2. 

```
df.loc[5,'col2']=np.nan 
df.loc[6,'col2']=np.nan
```

3. from the answer above

   df.col2[-2:]=np.nan
4. df['col2'][-2:]=np.nan